# How to go to searched word in TextView - Android

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, textview

Can somebody help me? I have the following problem:

I have a TextView and I can search some words, so that they're marked.

The TextView is named textView and it shows the text, I have an EditText Etxt to get the searched word and a Button to start the search. The code above is the code of the search. The app marks all found words big and italic. And I have a TextView text_total which shows the number of found words.

The problem: But if there is a searched word in the text below the shown screen, you must scroll and find the marked word:

```
int total = 0;
String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
String word;
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    word = array[i];
    if (word.toLowerCase().contains(word_search)) {
        String markiert = word.trim();
        st.append("<b><i>" + markiert + "</i></b>");
        total++;
    } else {
        st.append(word);
    }
    st.append("<br>");
}
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
text_total.setText("Ergebnisse: " + total);
```

Now, I have a problem because the text is too long to see all search results. I want that I have a 'back' and a 'next' button and the view goes to the next result if I click the next button and that the the found word goes automatically to the shown screen.

Does anyone know how to code this?

That's very important. Thanks for help!

Comment: save founded text to array. can you paste function of Next/Back button.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you show me how to code this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next & Back function is important. Paste it. but you can save founded text array and then call i+1 for next and i-1 for back

```
int total = 0;
String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
String[] markiert = new String[array.length]
String word;
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    word = array[i];
    if (word.toLowerCase().contains(word_search)) {
        markiert[i] = word.trim();//this is result in array do whatever you want with it
        st.append("<b><i>" + markiert[i] + "</i></b>");
        total++;
    } else {
        st.append(word);
    }
    st.append("<br>");
}
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
text_total.setText("Ergebnisse: " + total);
```

at First Show **markiert[0]** and for Next call markiert[0+1] then **markiert[N+1]**

Comment: Can you please show me how I must rewrite the code exactly, because it doesn't work. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks very much. I try it later.